# Where to save a Latex Template

Tags: templates, texworks

I am interested in saving a Latex template (that I wrote) so that I can use it via the "create new from template" file option. Can anyone tell me where I need to save this template in order to do this?

I am using a Mac OSX with Lion installed.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  Depends on which editor you are using: `TeXShop`/`\TeXworks`, something else?  The place is `~/Library/...` rest depends on the editor.

Comment: Just had the same issue with TeXWorks from TeXLive 2017 under Windows 7. After quite some searching I found the template directory under: `C:\Users\<username>\.texlive2017\texmf-config\texworks\templates`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For `TeXworks` to access a template via `File → New from Templates` place it under:

```
Library/TeXworks/templates/
```

For `TeXShop`, to access the files from `File → New from Stationary`, place the file under:

```
TeXShop/Stationery/
```

Comment: This worked perfectly (I am using TexWorks). Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @Peter Grill, I tried this but my file does not appear in the `Select Source` window that pops up after I choose `File->New From Stationary`. Do I have to save the file as a special format or something first? I'm on OSX Lion, using TeXShop v. 3.11.

Answer (score 6):

As is pointed out earlier, different TeX previewers manage this function differently. I am familiar with two previewers under Max OS 10.9:

[`TeXShop`](http://texshop.en.softonic.com/mac) 3.11 stores "stationary" in the folder

```
~/Library/TeXShop/Stationery
```

It uses two files, a TeX file containing the stationary and a text file containing a brief comment describing the stationary. The TeX file must have the extension ".tex" to be recognized. The comment file is optional, but if present must have the same name as the TeX file but with the extension ".txt".

[`TexWorks`](https://www.tug.org/texworks/) 0.4.4 stores "templates" in the folder

```
~/Library/TeXworks/templates
```

It uses a TeX file only. These files can be organized in folders.

---

1. `TeXShop` does not update its stationary menu during runtime, so it must be closed and reopened for the new stationary file to appear.`TeXWorks`, however, does update while open.
2. It's not clear whether updates to the previewers will save your added files. It would be good practice to save a backup copy of your stationary/templates.
3. Recent versions of MacOS hide the `Library` folder by default, so it may not be obvious how to find the folder you need. Paste the path into `Finders` `Go -> Go to folder...` command to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

For `TexMaker`, create your template and save it in a convenient folder or directory.  Now you just load it with `File → New by Copying an Existing File` menu selection.  You now have a copy of the template which you now save with an appropriate file name in the proper location for this new file.

Comment: You must have a new version, as I don't see a `File-New by Copying and Existing File` option. I am using `TeXworks 4.4`. Did you perhaps mean `File-Open`?

Comment: @doncherry: Opppsss, deleting comments shortly... I blame David Carlise for this, he taught me that reading documentation is evil, and I extended it to questions and answers without realizing it. :-)

Comment: I was trying to find out where to save the file...a "convenient folder" wasn't very clear :)