# Custom templates disappearing in TeXShop

Tags: templates, texshop

I have a custom template that I use for typesetting my homework assignments in TeXShop. Following the steps outlined in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82787/where-to-save-a-latex-template), I added this template to the directory of stored templates. However, the next time I open up TexShop after doing this, it appears that the templates I added have disappeared (i.e. they are not listed in the "Templates" drop-down menu).

Has anyone else encountered this problem, and if so, do you know of a solution?

Comment: Does the file exist in Finder?

Answer (score 2):

For `TexShop` the directory is `~/Library/TeXShop/Stationery` *not* `templates`.  When you restart `TeXShop` you need will see the file in `File/New from Stationary` menu.